# Rails - how to restrict user from entering more than one record per association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to rails and have not been able to find something for this.

In my app, I have Products, Reviews, & Users.

Reviews belongs_to users & products while both users and products "has_many" reviews.

However, I want to restrict users from entering multiple reviews per product (each product is unique). So if a user creates a review for a product and tries to write another review for the same product, they'd be told they are not allowed to but can edit their existing review.

My question is: Should I do this at the controller level, or is possible to do it with a validation (which seems like a simpler solution)? Just not sure how to approach it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can easily do this with a model validation, and an index would help as well.  Warning though, if you do the unique index without the accompanying ActiveRecord validation your saves will fail silently and cause a usability/debugging headache.

This should do it:

```
class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :user_id, :uniqueness => { :scope => :product_id,
    :message => "Users may only write one review per product." }
end
```

If you want to add the index, try this in a migration:

```
class AddUniquenessConstraintToReviews < ActiveRecord::Migration
  add_index  :review, [:user_id, :product_id],
    :name => "udx_reviews_on_user_and_product", :unique => true
end
```

**Edit**: As a full-time Rails dev I still refer to [the ActiveRecord docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html) for refreshers on the syntax of these things pretty regularly.  You should too!

Comment: Just to be clear, the above validation goes in the Review model correct? What is the benefit of adding a unique index?

Comment: @Zephyr4434 yes.  I just updated the answer to clarify the names of the classes containing my sample code.

Comment: @Zephyr4434 the unique index will come in handy if you ever have a second process writing to this table.  Possible scenarios are a background job queue or multiple app servers.  I've been bitten in the past when I had two work processing queues writing the same record at the same time.  Due to lack of uniqueness indexing I wound up with two records, even if each separate Rails engine though it was writing the only record of its kind.

Comment: Gotcha, that is very helpful thanks for the response. I will also take a look at the ActiveRecord docs regularly for a refresher

Answer (score 0):

Its better to validate in review model. The following method can be added to the validations.[Assuming you have associations set properly]

```
def validate_only_one_review_per_user
  !(@user.products.include? @product)
end
```